# Auto update cell data with =hyperlink() from one sheet to another

Tags: google-sheets, google-drive-api, google-apps

I want to automatically update sheet2 in a Google Spreadsheet document with data from sheet1. The problem I'm facing is the data also has a =hyperlink() associated with it. the standard, `='sheet1'!A1` only copies over the 'text' in the cell, and not the hyperlink.

**This is in cell A1 on sheet1**

```
=hyperlink("http://class.guhsd.net/index.php?EMP=DT50";"link")
```

**This what I entered in sheet2**

```
='sheet1'!A1
```

Is it possible to import the data with the hyperlink? If yes, can someone please share the formula with me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following formula:

In sheet2:

```
=INDIRECT("sheet1!A1")
```

Comment: wchiquito, THANK YOU! Exactly what I was looking for.